# (Vscode) Automatically attach debugger to android process to run Android Studio app

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code

Recently I have found that running android studio apps in vscode android environment is much faster than in Android Studio IDE. Basically all I have to do is open Android Studio and Vscode at the same time and run apps on Vscode (with android extension installed and android environment activated).

However, every time I run the app, I have to click on the 'attach debugger to android process' button beforehand for the app to be launched.

[image]

Is there anyway I can automate the 'attach debugger' process so that all I have to do is click the Run button on Vscode only?

[image]

I have searched for similar questions yet no solution was found. Most were related to Visual Studio or just manually clicking the 'attach debugger' button (which I find a bit annoying).

Could you show me the way to do attach debugger to android process automatically?